# Overwrite the url validator in CKAN

Tags: python, ckan

I want overwrite the url validator of ckan in my plugin. I have followed a tutorial (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/tree/master/ckanext/example_idatasetform) and my plugin is this:

```
import logging

import ckan.plugins as plugins
import ckan.plugins.toolkit as toolkit

def custom_url_validator(key, data, errors, context):

   ''' Checks that the provided value is a valid URL '''
   import urlparse
   import string

   model = context['model']
   session = context['session']

   url = data.get(key, None)
   if not url:
       return

   pieces = urlparse.urlparse(url)
   if all([pieces.scheme, pieces.netloc]) and \
      set(pieces.netloc) <= set(string.letters + string.digits + '-.:') and \
      pieces.scheme in ['http', 'https']:
      return

   errors[key].append(_('Custom: Please provide a valid URL'))

class MyPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin, toolkit.DefaultDatasetForm):

   plugins.implements(plugins.IConfigurer)
   plugins.implements(plugins.IDatasetForm)

   # IConfigurer

   def update_config(self, config_):
       toolkit.add_template_directory(config_, 'templates')
       toolkit.add_public_directory(config_, 'public')

   """ Redefine if this plugin is a default fallback"""
   def is_fallback(self):
       # Return True to register this plugin as the default handler for
       # package types not handled by any other IDatasetForm plugin.
       return True

   """ Define package types this plugin should be used for has to overwritten because of TODO"""
   def package_types(self):
       # This plugin doesn't handle any special package types, it just
       # registers itself as the default (above).
       return []

   def _modify_package_schema(self, schema):

       schema.update({
           # Custom extras
           'image_url':[toolkit.get_validator('ignore_missing'), unicode, custom_url_validator]
       })
       schema.update({
           # Custom extras
           'url':[toolkit.get_validator('ignore_missing'), unicode, custom_url_validator]
       })
       return schema

   def create_package_schema(self):

       schema = super(MyPlugin, self).create_package_schema()
       schema = self._modify_package_schema(schema)

       return schema

   def update_package_schema(self):
       schema = super(MyPlugin, self).update_package_schema()
       schema = self._modify_package_schema(schema)
       return schema

   def show_package_schema(self):
       schema = super(MyPlugin, self).show_package_schema()

       schema.update({
           # Custom extras
           # Yes, we really do need validators on show, or CKAN crashes
           'image_url':[toolkit.get_validator('ignore_missing'), unicode, custom_url_validator]
       })
       schema.update({
           # Custom extras
           # Yes, we really do need validators on show, or CKAN crashes
           'url':[toolkit.get_validator('ignore_missing'), unicode, custom_url_validator]
       })

       return schema
```

I do not get this to work. Do I have to do something else?

Comment: Also, have you considered contributing this change to CKAN, for everyone's benefit?

Comment: If you debug it, how far does it get? Is your plugin enabled? Does the modified schema register? Does the validator get called? And how are you creating a dataset? API or form?

Comment: I'm trying to create a related through CKAN API 3 (related_create). The plugin is enabled because other things are working.  The validator is not called (I print a log but this is not shown).

Comment: I am making this because i want to learn to make a validator in a ckan extension. When it works i will make a pullrequest to github repository of ckan to improve the validation of URLs CKAN

Answer (score 0):

You have inserted this new validator into the **package** schema, for when you create or update a **package** (dataset). However you are using the related_create API call, which creates a **related** object instead, explaining why it doesn't use your package validator.

By the way, we announced a month ago on the list that 'related' is deprecated, will be removed in the next release (CKAN 2.5) so you should transition to ckanext-showcase instead.

However your custom_url_validator sounds like a welcome improvement for resource URLs and encourage you to continue with a PR for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `unicode` call, that doesn't look like a valid converter or validator.  Should this be `toolkit.get_converter('extras_unicode_convert')`, or is this something you wrote that is not shown?

You're also missing the `convert_to_extras` and `convert_from_extras` calls.  You don't need to call `schema.update` for every custom extra, though that won't break anything.

Try replacing your `_modify_package_schema` and `show_package_schema` with the following, and note the ordering of the validators and converters in both `_modify_package_schema` and `show_package_schema`:

```
def _modify_package_schema(self, schema):
    schema.update({
        # Custom extras
        'image_url':[toolkit.get_validator('ignore_missing'),
                     toolkit.get_converter('extras_unicode_convert'),
                     custom_url_validator,
                     toolkit.get_converter('convert_to_extras')],
        'url':[toolkit.get_validator('ignore_missing'),
               toolkit.get_converter('extras_unicode_convert'),
               custom_url_validator,
               toolkit.get_converter('convert_to_extras')]
    })
    return schema

...

def show_package_schema(self):
    schema = super(MyPlugin, self).show_package_schema()

    schema.update({
        # Custom extras
        'image_url':[toolkit.get_converter('convert_from_extras'),
                     toolkit.get_validator('ignore_missing'),
                     toolkit.get_converter('extras_unicode_convert'),
                     custom_url_validator],
        'url':[toolkit.get_converter('convert_from_extras'),
               toolkit.get_validator('ignore_missing'),
               toolkit.get_converter('extras_unicode_convert'),
               custom_url_validator]
    })
    return schema
```